Android AutoStart is not working unless user swipes up from the Standby Screen
I am trying to implement AutoStart mode on Android application (Kotlin,SDK 33)My current implementation only works when I swipe the screen up to exit standby mode. What should I change in my code so that the device is starting the app without a need to swipe up the screen.I also need to implement Kiosk mode to restrict the app to just one app usage, maybe Kiosk mode has functionality to implement AutoStart mode properly?
I would really appreciate any suggestions!
Manifest:
 <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

Boot Receiver:
class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            val launchIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            context?.startActivity(launchIntent)
        }
    }
}


That broadcast only gets fired when your device is rebooted, I am not sure what you are expecting here. Swiping your app away from the recent's list has no effect here because you device would have been off anyway and there would be nothing in that list to begin with

Also in more recent versions of Android you need a special permission to be able to launch an activity from the background like your app would be upon boot

Have your app be the launcher app for the device.

@tyczj Thanks for your response. I expect the application to start when device is restarted without without swiping up the screen. If I do not touch the screen, the app never starts. When I swipe up shortly after reboot, the app starts.
I need to implement Kiosk mode anyway, maybe some Kiosk mode libraries could handle this issue?

@CommonsWare My app does not restart/launch the device. I do it manually using power button.

@RomanKozulia there is no library to help you here, you would need to disable the lock screen on the device so then the user does not have to swipe (I dont know if every device have this option). Then you implementation should work assuming you have the permission to do so

Thanks @tyczj for your response, so I should not attempt to disable lock screen programmatically, it should be done on the device, correct?

@RomanKozulia you cannot disable the lock screen via your app, that would be a major security issue in Android for obvious reasons, you have to do it manually

"My app does not restart/launch the device. I do it manually using power button." -- the launcher app is what appears on the device when the device starts up. On a conventional phone or tablet, it will display a home screen (wallpaper, icons, etc.) and offer some form of app launcher (e.g., an app drawer). On a kiosk device, the launcher is whatever the purpose is of the kiosk device.

@tyczj thanks for your help. Disabling lock screen did the trick!

@CommonsWare thanks for your comment, could you suggest how to implement a Kiosk mode. Is Google's Lock Task Mode what I need?
In the company where I work, we have an Android app that has Kiosk mode, but it doesn't work properly. On start I can still see other apps on the screen.
Should I try to convince management to buy a third-party solution, or it is feasible to implement Kiosk mode myself (I have two days deadline)?

"Is Google's Lock Task Mode what I need?" -- that is where I would start. "it is feasible to implement Kiosk mode myself" -- I have no idea, sorry.

@CommonWare Thank you, I will try Lock Task Mode as you suggested.
